# Change output after each run to one output after all runs

Tags: java, output

My program is pretty much all finished except for the output, I want it to display everything in one output rather than one after each run, it is supposed to run 500 times but made it only 10 until I have this problem fixed.

```
package assignment5;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.text.*;
public class assignment5
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        lottery pic=new lottery();for(int i = 0; i <10; i++)
        {
            pic.Get_player_numbers();
            pic.Get_jackpot_number();
            pic.Check_winner ();
            pic.Write_data();

        }
    }
}
class lottery
{
    int[] picks= new int[5];
    int[] cpick=new int[5];
    int i;
    int j,c;
    int match=0;
    double matchcount0=0;
    double matchcount1=0;
    double matchcount2=0;
    double matchcount3=0;
    double matchcount4=0;
    double matchcount5=0;
    int jackpot = 25000000;
    int payout;

    void Get_player_numbers ()
    {
        int temp,dupflag=0;
        for(i=0;i<=4;++i)
        {
            //YOU DO NOT NEED THE CNUMBERFLAG
            //IF YOU GENERATED THE NUMBERS CORRECLTY, THE COMPUTER WILL NOT GENERATE ONE ABOVE 99 OR LESS THAN 1
            dupflag=0;
            while(dupflag==0)
            {
                temp = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*99)+1;
                dupflag=1;
                for(c=0;c<=i;++c)
                {
                    if(temp==picks[c])
                    {
                        dupflag=0;
                    }
                }//inner for loop
                if(dupflag==1)  
                    picks[i]=temp;
            }
        }       
    }

    //void jackpot()
    void Get_jackpot_number()
    {
        int ctemp,cdupflag=0;
        for(j=0;j<=4;++j)
        {
            //YOU DO NOT NEED THE CNUMBERFLAG
            //IF YOU GENERATED THE NUMBERS CORRECLTY, THE COMPUTER WILL NOT GENERATE ONE ABOVE 99 OR LESS THAN 1
            cdupflag=0;
            while(cdupflag==0)
            {
                ctemp = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*99)+1;
                cdupflag=1;
                for(c=0;c<=j;++c)
                {
                    if(ctemp==cpick[c])
                    {
                        cdupflag=0;
                    }
                }//inner for loop
                if(cdupflag==1) 
                    cpick[j]=ctemp;
            }
        }
        String Jackpot="Computer Lottery numbers are: "+"\n";
        //String computer = "";
        for(j=0;j<=4;++j)
        {
            if(j==4)
                Jackpot=Jackpot+cpick[j];   
            else
                Jackpot=Jackpot+cpick[j]+"-";
        }
    }

    void Check_winner ()
    {
        match=0;

        for(int i=0;i<=4;++i)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<=4;++j)
            {
                if(picks[i]==cpick[j])
                {
                    match=match+1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void Write_data ()
    {

        if(match==0)
        {
            matchcount0=matchcount0+1;

            payout=0;
            jackpot=jackpot+25000;
        }
        else if(match==1)
        {
            matchcount1=matchcount1+1;

            payout=100;
            jackpot=jackpot+100000;
        }
        else if(match==2)
        {
            matchcount2=matchcount2+1;

            jackpot=jackpot+250000;
            payout=1000;
        }
        else if(match==3)
        {
            matchcount3=matchcount3+1;

            jackpot=jackpot+500000;
            payout=10000;
        }
        else if(match==4)
        {
            matchcount4=matchcount4+1;

            jackpot=jackpot+1000000;
            payout=100000;
        }
        else if(match==5)
        {
            matchcount5=matchcount5+1;

            payout=jackpot;
            jackpot=jackpot-jackpot+2500000;
        }

        System.out.println("Current Jackpot     Player#         Winner#          #Matched      Payout\n"+jackpot+"         "+picks[0]+" "+picks[1]+" "+picks[2]+" "+picks[3]+" "+picks[4]+"    "+cpick[0]+" "+cpick[1]+" "+cpick[2]+" "+cpick[3]+" "+cpick[4]+"        "+match+"            "+payout+"\nThe percent of plays where 0 numbers matched = "+matchcount0/i*100+"%\nThe percent of plays where 1 numbers matched = "+matchcount1/10+"%\nThe percent of plays where 2 numbers matched = "+matchcount2/10+"%\nThe percent of plays where 3 numbers matched = "+matchcount3/10+"%\nThe percent of plays where 4 numbers matched = "+matchcount4/10+"%\nThe percent of plays where 5 numbers matched = "+matchcount5/10+"%\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, try to explain the core of your problem. We do not need to see your whole application (I suppose) to give you some advice. Let us focus on the lines that really matter.

Answer (score 1):

Use StringBuilder class. In each run you can just append new line two your StringBuilder instance.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Current Jackpot player...");
}
```

When everything is done you can use

```
builder.toString();
```

to get your output.